# error[E0207]: the type parameter `T` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust, substrate-parachain-template

Below is my block of code where I am implementing this trait Config. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here I keep getting error "the type parameter T is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates"

```
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
    type Who;
    type RuntimeEvent;
    type OriginSuccess;
    type SchemaCreatorId;
    type MaxEncodedSchemaLength;
    type WeightInfo;
    type EnsureOrigin;
    type Origin;
}
impl<T: frame_system::Config> Config for Test {
    type Who = u64;
    type RuntimeEvent = Event<T>;
    type EnsureOrigin = frame_system::EnsureSignedBy<Self::Who, Self::AccountId>;
    type OriginSuccess = ();
    type SchemaCreatorId = AccountId32;
    type MaxEncodedSchemaLength = Self::MaxEncodedSchemaLength;
    type WeightInfo = Self::WeightInfo;
}
```

Attached is the screenshot of the error. [image: unconstrained type parameter]
Also the codefile [CodeFile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MCfosjzdB9lSmAvZkZA__vCV52CtBGgp/view?usp=sharing)
If anyone can point me what I am doing wrong that would be help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's because you are basically defining a trait that is bound by `frame_system::Config`, meaning the type that must implement your `Config` trait must also implement `frame_system::Config`

what you want to do is something like this:

```
impl my_pallet::Config for Test{...}
```

this will work only if Test already implements `frame_system::Config` (which it does in substrate https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a7bc9c2a8c0a14fd6033de1f972a11a2b3dbb73a/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L217

or for tests

https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/700c3a186e55d0d6542c564ccff17260238ed752/pallets/template/src/mock.rs#L24
)

Comment: Thanks this did help

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of examples here.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a7bc9c2a8c0a14fd6033de1f972a11a2b3dbb73a/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L246-L251

You just need `impl xxx::Config for Runtime/Test { ... }`.